# How to determine the correct hardness setting for Water-Right Sanitizer Plus Softener

Tags: water-softener

We have a Water-Right Impression Series Sanitizer Plus Softener, and our water has been "just right" for a number of years, up until about three weeks ago. Around that time the water went *really* soft, leaving my wife in particular feeling like she can't get soap completely off her skin or hair. If this is something that I can address through the use of a hardness test and updating the settings myself, I'd prefer to do that than calling out a plumber for obvious reasons.

The problem is that while Water-Right has a [great video showing how to make adjustments to the unit's settings (including hardness) on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAfvWlWuUXM):

- There is no guidance in the owner's manual for choosing a setting
- I have not been able to find any guidance online regarding the setting
- Water-Right has not responded to my request for information

So does anyone know this unit, and know what I would need to do in order to adjust the setting properly? Or know enough about the unit to tell me why I should call in a plumber with experience on these units instead of trying to address it myself?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think it is personal preference some folks don’t mind water that is on the hard side and some like the water so soft it taste like salt (ok maybe not quite that bad). I would set it and see what you think how your shampoo foams up and the taste are the big things I notice.

Comment: Why the sudden change? Has the incoming water changed or has a setting been changed by accident?

Comment: You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know how to participate here with upvotes for helpful information and checks for accepted answers.

Comment: @SolarMike I actually have no idea. Neither of us touch the head units of our water treatment system, we haven't changed brands of solar salt, and we haven't had a significant change in rainfall patterns here. I have not been able to find anything online about what external factors would cause a sudden change.

Comment: i would reach out to your water provider; in my case, it's the city. they have data on water hardness and should be able to tell you if something has recently changed. you won't really see guidance on water softeners themselves because they can be installed anywhere, within a wide range of hardness levels.

Comment: I am on well water, so there's not much to go on out here sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Ed Beal is right about personal preference. Although water that is too hard or too soft can also have implications for your water system and equipment such as pumps, dishwashers, etc.
Dealing strictly with the issue that your wife is having with soap not rinsing off easily you'll need to increase the hardness of your water. In order to determine how much, go to a local pool supply store and purchase a simple pool/spa water testing kit. You don't need anything fancy, you only want to measure PH levels. Follow the instructions and measure the current PH level of your water. That will give you a base point. Slowly adjust your water softener to increase the PH in small increments. Once you have it at a comfortable point measure it again and use that as your target PH level. You should be able to find info on adjusting PH in the instruction manual or on-line.
The link you posted in your question explains how to adjust hardness when following the installer setup instructions.

Comment: I was unaware that pH could affect the softness of the water. The problem is, there is only one setting available to me with this head unit, and it is the hardness.

Comment: An additional bit of information here, we actually have a WaterRight Impression Series Acid Neutralizer in line _before_ the sanitizer, but strangely enough that doesn't have any settings in the head unit besides time of day, regen interval, and regen time.

Comment: Measuring PH is how you measure water hardness - that is why I suggested you test it. The higher the PH the harder the water. Did you view the video link in your original post? It explains how to adjust the hardness with your softener. It's in the set-up instructions.

Comment: I got a HACH 5B hardness test kit since I couldn't find a conversion of pH to grains per gallon, which is how this water treatment system works. As it turns out, the water coming directly from the well is 4 grains per gallon (the treated water, not surprisingly, measured out at less than 1 grain per gallon). So I've adjusted the sanitizer / softener to 4 gpg, and we'll see if it play nicer.

Comment: Only way to do it. Keep adjusting the setting until you're happy.

Answer (score 0):

For the Water-Right Sanitizer Plus (where the Plus is softening), you need to calculate the hardness of the untreated water in Grains Per Gallon (gpg), because that's the only thing you can enter into the control panel for the unit related to water softening. Whatever it takes to be able to get that measurement in fairly precise terms (the HACH 5B kit gives you single grain resolution) is best to dial it in as closely as possible. The system appears to correct itself within two regeneration cycles.